# How can I fix a Java-GUI-program (swing), that it works with awesome-wm?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awesome-wm

The swing-UI of Java-programs doesn't work perfectly together with the [awesome-wm](http://awesome.naquadah.org/). awesome is a window-manager for UNIX, that automatically resizes program-windows, and the Swing-UI doesn't recognize these resizes correctly. I don't care if awesome or Java is guilty, what I wanna know if I can change my Java-programs in a way, that they will work with awesome. So that users of my programs get the correct experience, even when they use exotic window-managers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the man page of awesome:

```
BUGS
   Of course there´s no bug in awesome. But there may be unexpected behaviours.

   Java applications which use the XToolkit/XAWT backend may draw grey windows only. The XToolkit/XAWT backend breaks ICCCM-compliance
   in recent JDK 1.5 and early JDK 1.6 versions, because it assumes a reparenting window manager. As a workaround you can use JDK 1.4
   (which doesn´t contain the XToolkit/XAWT backend) or you can set the following environment variable (to use the older Motif backend
   instead): AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit
```

Comment: This brings up the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/motif21/libmawt.so

Comment: java-6-openjdk package only has i386/xawt/libmawt.so and i386/headless/libmawt.so. Sun JDK also includes i386/motif21/libmawt.so

Comment: This solution isn't perfect. If you use Netbeans IDE, setting AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit will result in locking out the keyboard b/c of an old swing bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6506617. MToolkit may not give you any problems, just remember - if your keyboard starts to loose focus, you may need to use AWT_TOOLKIT=XToolkit.

Answer (score 51):

Easiest workaround - get [wmname from suckless](http://tools.suckless.org/wmname) and use it to set the name of the window manager to LG3D:

```
wmname LG3D
```

98% of the time this will fix the issue.

Comment: This is really the only viable option, as the AWT_TOOLKIT override no longer works on modern versions of Java, yet, this hack works on modern javas.  You would not believe how many months I spent trying to solve this problem before I realised my window manager was causing it.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks! And we can install `wmname` with `sudo apt-get install suckless-tools`.

Comment: Works  also for me Netbeans 8 and Awesome3

Answer (score 3):

You *might* find that this is a similar problem to that experienced with using Compiz and Java (on Ubuntu at least), but I am guessing.

The fix for this (taken from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=506686)) is to add the following environment variable to your program:

```
AWT_TOOLKIT="MToolkit"
```